# Why can I connect to mysql through ssh -> mysql, but cannot connect through a ssh tunnel, address is bound to localhost(bind-address 127.0.0.1)?

Tags: mysql, ssh

I can connect to the server by ssh (`ssh #ssh_user#@#ssh_host#`) and then use `mysql -u#db_user# -p#db_password#`. Then I can use the mysql command line as usual, but I am trying to setup DBeaver so I have a client interface for it. Is it impossible to do when the bind-address is set to localhost?

SSH tunnel settings

```
host: #ssh_host#
port: 22
user: #ssh_user#
auth: (key)
```

SSH tunnel itself works, I tried it with `ssh -L 23:#ssh_host#:22 #ssh_user#@#ssh_host#`

Comment: Try `ssh #ssh_user#@#ssh_host# -L 3309:localhost:3306`, then from local, `mysql -u #db_user# -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3309`.

Comment: It refuses the connection. `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`