# Connect to remote db with ssh tunneling in DBeaver

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, dbeaver

I know this question was already asked before (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652978/why-can-i-connect-to-mysql-through-ssh-mysql-but-cannot-connect-through-a-ss)), but still I could not find a solution and those posts are quite old.

So I am able to connect to the remote db with an ssh connection and then use the command line like this:

```
// Putty SSH Connection
host: ssh.strato.de
port: 22
username: xxxxxxx 
password: xxxxxxx 

// connect to mysql with terminal
mysql -h rdbms -u xxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxx
```

If I try the same with ssh-tunneling in DBeaver I get an connection error

[image]

The ssh-tunneling itself seems to work. If I use the same credentials as above and press "Test tunnel configuration" I get a success message.

[image]

I tried several other options for port and host (localhost, rdbms.strato.de, etc), which I found via mysql `show variables;` `show processlist;` `show user();`, but none of them worked.
The Strato Support told me that I can only connect to the db internally with phpmyadmin or remotely wiht putty and mysql, but since the last method is working, shouldn't ssh-tunneling also work?

Comment: I was having the same issue, with the same response from the server. I managed to get a functioning connection by creating a new one using the MariaDb driver instead of the MySQL one.

Comment: Du you also use Strato? Can you tell me your connection settings? I could not figure out how to set up the connection properly.

Comment: No, sorry. I used pretty much all the defaults from DBeaver. The only thing I changed was the host port for my setup and then choosing the driver did the trick.

Comment: I had the same issue. Turns out that I have iptables policy deny so I solved it by allowing loopback connections.

Answer (score 28):

### Dbeaver - Database connection using SSH Tunnel

- Open dbeaver
- Click on "**New Database Connection**", in the following "**main**" window enter the MySQL server host relative to the SSH server, and MySQL running port, my setting is default (`localhost`, `3306`)
  specify MySQL user to connect with and user password.
  [image: dbeaver main]
- In the "**SSH**" part, specify the SSH host, port, user also the authentication method used, like SSH private key
  [image: dbeaver ssh]
  Test connection and use.

Comment: This is also listed in the DBeaver docs: https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/SSH-Configuration/ - they explain Port Forwarding and Jump servers/Gateway server too.

Comment: My notes from the problems I had: 1) I used the **Authentication Method: Agent** (I'm on linux). 2) I'm using AWS RDS and that requires setting the **Advanced > Remote host**. 3) Port forwarding via **Advanced > Local port** and **Advanced > Remote port**: in theory this should be automatic, but I found it useful to set them both to the expected database port (5432 for postgres)

Comment: I have e xactly the same setup but still getting the error above

Comment: You might need to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the main tab.