# Whitelisting dev ip addresses for GCP development database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jdbc, google-cloud-networking

I have a development database hosted on GCP that I'd like my team to have access to. Ideally, I'd like people to be able to use any SQL client they'd like but so far, only DBeaver works with the Postgres/SSL enabled configuration we have. Currently, we have people at their personal houses, so the IP addresses can and do change. We'd like to enable access from their development machines, but not the whole world. We started with whitelisting IP addresses (as returned by whatismyip.com), but that's not very robust. What's a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to remote db with ssh tunneling in DBeaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481470/connect-to-remote-db-with-ssh-tunneling-in-dbeaver)

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommend whitelisting IP addresses. Use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy.

[About the Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

You can then disable client SSL as the proxy will authenticate and encrypt all communications.

Comment: Not sure if one can configure a proxy as tunnel: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy ...one would need to know the values to set in the GUI: https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Proxy-configuration/#how-to-configure-a-proxy-for-external-databases-access probably `127.0.0.1:5432` or `tcp:5432`. `-enable_iam_login` works with Postgres only.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - The proxy is its own tunnel. The SQL Auth Proxy is the official solution and is built into services such as App Engine and Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with Identity Aware Proxy(IAP) - https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

Basically create one VM to run Cloud sql proxy

`cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432`

Then grant your users necessary IAM permissions to start an IAP tunnel to that VM, where they can run a similar command to below from their laptop -

`gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel YOUR-VM-NAME --zone ZONE 5432 --local-host-port=localhost:5432`

The users then connect to the DB on loopback, which is securely tunneled through IAP.

Reference - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/start-iap-tunnel

Comment: This would work except that IAP TCP Tunnels are rate limited. For a temporary low bandwidth solution, yes, but not for long-term deployment or for large data transfers. The official solution is the Cloud SQL Auth proxy installed at the client.